# Having trouble using ggplot2 function stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
#means and SEs
s2humanlikem<-c(1.895,1.658,2.684,2.421,2.921,2.158,3.632,2.737,4.526,4.105)
s2humanlikese<-c(.199,.157,.250,.234,.243,.225,.197,.235,.145,.180)
s2agent<-c("Software","Software","Machine","Machine","Robot","Robot","Android","Android","Human","Human")
Story<-c("Cooperative","Self-interested")

#combine into dataframe
hri2<-data.frame(s2agent,s2humanlikem,s2humanlikese,Story)

#make numeric and factor
hri2$s2agent <- factor(hri2$s2agent, levels = c("Software","Machine", "Robot", "Android","Human"))
hri2$s2humanlikem<-as.numeric(levels(hri2$s2humanlikem))[hri2$s2humanlikem]
hri2$s2humanlikese<-as.numeric(levels(hri2$s2humanlikese))[hri2$s2humanlikese]
```

that I'm trying to plot using the following code:

```
ggplot(hri2,aes(x=s2agent,y=s2humanlikem,group=Story)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(x=seq(length((s2agent)))),se=F,method="lm",formula=y~poly(x,4)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(length(unique(hri2$s2agent))),labels=levels(hri2$s2agent))
```

However as you can see, the graph's axes are wonky. The two lines are also misaligned for some reason and I can't figure out why. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting you `x` to numeric and removing the `seq` in `stat_smooth` gives the desired result:

```
ggplot(hri2,aes(x=as.numeric(s2agent),y=s2humanlikem,group=Story)) +
  stat_smooth(se=FALSE,method="lm",formula=y~poly(x,4)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(length(unique(hri2$s2agent))),labels=levels(hri2$s2agent))
```

this results in the following plot:
[image]

---

UPDATE: When you want to include the SE in the plot, you will have to plot from the original dataframe from which you calculated the `mean` and the `se`.

If you want to use the data you provided, you could for example use the following:

```
ggplot(hri2,aes(x=s2agent,y=s2humanlikem,group=Story)) +
  geom_line(color="blue",size=1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=s2humanlikem-s2humanlikese, ymax=s2humanlikem+s2humanlikese), alpha=0.3) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

this gives:
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use se=TRUE here? This function seems to calculate the standard error manually, but I've specified it in the data frame. (Error bars work, but it'd be nice to have the shaded area.) Thanks.

Comment: No, because you have only one observation for each x-value for each group. You can't calculate a SE from one value.

Comment: @user3298090 I've added an alternative for including the SE. Is this what you're looking for?